# What is the storage size of a BIT (8) NULL column, and is it any different than BIT (7) or BIT (8) NOT NULL?

Tags: mysql, storage

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785588/whats-the-storage-size-of-bit1) and [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html), the storage requirements for a BIT (**M**) field in MySQL are "approximately (**M**+7)/8 bytes".  This seems awfully vague, and the answers given there don't specify whether this is rounding up or down on the remainder. Which is it?

Specifically, (BIT(7)+7)/8 = 1.75. Is this one or two bytes? -- And is the bit used to determine NULL count towards an extra bit as in the case of SIGNED integers, making BIT (8) (one byte) effectively BIT (9) (two bytes)?

Or is every NULL bit stored in a separate byte at the head of the record, as suggested elsewhere?

Is it true that BIT (**M**) limits the **value** of the field, padding it physically with zeros only, but INT (**N**) doesn't? That seems inconsistent. Isn't the (N) dangerous if, *even on the command line*, it just tells it to calculate the same but hide the missing digits? -> Is the same true for BIT (M), e.g. can BIT (3) store up to 8 bits = minimum byte length?

Finally, why does the MySQL documentation say on the exact same page that:

> Each `BIT`(**`M`**) column takes ***`M`*** bits of storage space. Although an
>   individual `BIT` column is not 4-byte aligned, **`NDB`** reserves 4 bytes (32
>   bits) per row for the first 1-32 bits needed for `BIT` columns, then
>   another 4 bytes for bits 33-64, and so on.

How does this jibe with the above, or are the storage requirements different because it is for NDB databases?

*Note: I'm aware that MySQL no longer treats BIT as an alias for TINYINT (converting each bit into a byte)...*

To clarify -- This is a programming question: I am trying to determine how many bits I should set aside in the *limit* for a bunch of NOT NULL bitmask fields in my SQL. (to allow for additional flags; I only use four or five flags.) What is the recommended *per-byte limit?* The additional flags will probably never be used, and I'd prefer to limit the number of possible values in the bitmask.

Comment: I would suggest taking this over to serverfault.

Comment: This is a programming question, though; see above.

Comment: I believe they meant `DIV` instead of the `/`, i.e. `(M+7) DIV 8`.

Comment: Personally, I find that the 1 bit for `NULL` to be so insignificant in the grand scheme that I ignore it.

Comment: I'm more worried about accidentally getting junk data in my bitmask. If a bitmask has only 4 possible flags plus a few spare flag bits, and a query accidentally treats it as a bool or int or whatever, then it's easier to control for invalid combos. If BIT (3) actually allows 8 bits but simply truncates the output, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @AndriyM so basically the logical, intuitive version is actually right? ;)

Comment: I guess so. (Not sure what you mean by that. My understanding of the formula is that a non-NULL BIT(7) or BIT(8) takes up 1 byte, while e.g. a non-NULL BIT(9) takes up 2 bytes.)

Comment: Yes, that would be intuitive, since 8+7 is one less than (the amount needed for) two bytes. The normal "plain english" interpretation of "*approximately* (7+7)/8" would be to round up on the remainder, since 1.75 is obviously greater than 1. It makes *much* more sense to say "a BIT field reserves at minimum one byte, and takes up to 8 bits per byte." My only question would be, does a NULL BIT(8) and a NULL BIT(7) take up the same number of bytes? My assumption would be that the null bits are stored in a separate set of 4 bytes, as pointers.

Comment: NDB Cluster is a totally different implementation than InnoDB/MyISAM/etc.  So, it could well be that NDB allocates in 4-byte chunks, while the rest do 1-byte chunks.

Comment: Pre-allocating flags for later use is usually folly.  And it leads to ugly column names.